# Logcat not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-gradle-plugin

I changed the applicationId of my app in build.gradle under app folder from

```
defaultConfig{
    applicationId "com.sample.sampleapp"
    ....
}
```

to

```
defaultConfig{
    applicationId "com.sample.app"
    ....
}
```

Now, the logcat is not showing even though the filter configuration is configured by package name: `com.sample.app`

Any ideas? Sorry, I'm new to Android Studio. Big thanks in advance.

Comment: is it change package name in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Already tried restarting android studio and my laptop. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @HareshChhelana, yes. Package name in Manifest is the same with build.gradle.

Comment: Okay good have you check project src directory structure after change applicationId is change as per build.gradle ?

Comment: @John, Click File->Invalidate Caches/ Restart...

Comment: @HareshChhelana, yes. MainActivity is located under `com.sample.app` and `com.sample.sampleapp` doesn't exist anymore.